# .net 4.5 foreign key data annotation c#

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, data-annotations

Is the `[foreign key("blah")]` not supported in .net 4.5 anymore ? When I import in the dataannotations model, intellisense tells me that it doesn't exist. The same happens with the inverse property. Are they trying to get us to use the fluent api for these types of opperations instead ? Are there any standards for fluent api vs data annotations ?

Model :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DevCentral.Entities
{   
    public partial class Category
    {    
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(75), MinLength(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ClassificationId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ClassificationId"), InverseProperty("Categories")]
        public virtual Classification Classification { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ForeignKey is still very much alive in .net 4.5, check:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute.aspx

You might be missing a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll assembly in your project.

**Update:**
As @mtleising commented, the namespace for `ForeignKeyAttribute` as of .net 4.5 is  `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`

Comment: I definitely have it included.. I'm using .Net 4.5 and version 4.0 of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. I have some of the DataAnnotations, like the Key, Max and Min Length, required, but ForeignKey isn't there, not in intellisense or anything.. It has me lost. Thanks for clarifying though. Also, any tips on conventions with what does and doesn't belong as a data annotation?

Comment: Ok just an FYI, It turns out that the [ForeignKey] annotation is in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Comment: That's right, the web address for the documentation had that hinted already but I only refeered to the assembly file name, sorry.