# Foreign Keys on fields with different name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a table called tbGeneralOptions which holds some default answers to questions in my application. The Options are Yes, No, N/A with the values of 1,2,3 respectively.

```
public class tbGeneralOption
{
    public int tbGeneralOptionID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an Option")]
    [Display(Name = "Option")]
    public string OptionName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tbFamilyMember> tbFamilyMember { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tbFamily> tbFamily { get; set; }

}
```

In my tbFamilyMember Table I am storing the values from the above Options on the fields of Disability and PhotoPermission.

```
public class tbFamilyMember
{
    [Display(Name = "Family Member ID")]
    public int tbFamilyMemberID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Family ID")]
    public int tbFamilyID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Role")]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public int tbFamilyRoleID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select if the Family Member has a disability")]
    [Display(Name = "Disability")]
    public int Disability { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select if the Family Member has given permission for photographs")]
    [Display(Name = "Photo Permission")]
    public int PhotoPermission { get; set; }

    public virtual tbFamily tbFamily { get; set; }
    public virtual tbFamilyRole tbFamilyRole { get; set; }
    public virtual tbGeneralOption tbGeneralOption { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is now how to display the OptionName for the stored value in my view.

I am assuming I can make the link through foreign keys but can this be done if the field names don't match?

Comment: Look if this question can help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572214/net-4-5-foreign-key-data-annotation-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments below, you don't need `tbGeneralOption` at all, since your options per type are fixed and static - options are not dynamically added. So you should create options as boolean properties on the types that have options. Also, you can remove error messages for these options, because options are not required, by definition.

I removed properties `tbFamilyID` and `tbFamilyRoleID` because you are already referencing family and familyRole at the bottom and IDs are accessible thought there, in case you need to display them , which you probably shouldn't. Here is updated model for family member:

```
public class tbFamilyMember
{
    public int tbFamilyMemberID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Disability")]
    public bool Disability { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Photo Permission")]
    public bool PhotoPermission { get; set; }

    public virtual tbFamily tbFamily { get; set; }
    public virtual tbFamilyRole tbFamilyRole { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But how does that link to the Disability or PhotoPermission field? In my View I currently have @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Disability) which displays the value of 2 But I need something like @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Disability.tbGeneralOption.OptionName)

Comment: So, `tbFamilyMember.Disability` is actually one of general options from `tbGeneralOption` table?

Comment: Then you need to reflect that in your model. So `tbFamilyMember.Option` should not be `int`, but `tbGeneralOption` type. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: One more question: why do you have tbGeneralOption, if options are just properties of family member and can be selected or not (boolean)?

Comment: tbGeneralOption is used across the application not just with the Family Member. I was trying to cut down on additional tables which were storing the same values. If there is a better way of doing this..

Comment: If options are "static" for a certain type, i.e. family member always has `Disability` and `PhotoPermition` and only those, then you don't need `tbGeneralOption`, just add options as boolean properties, nullable if you need three values (for which I don't see the need, you either have an option or don't). If options are "dynamic" and any number of them could be added to a family member at runtime, then you need `tbGeneralOption`, but `tbFamilyMember` should have a property which is a collection of `tbGeneralOption`. Which one is your case?

Comment: In addition to the above answer I have also created Editor and Display templates for my Boolean properties. Examples are http://zootfroot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/override-aspnet-mvc-3-nullable-boolean.html and http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2011/11/22/using-templates-to-display-boolean-values-as-yes-no-options.aspx